# Rails get one record without loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that has a main_image per asset and in the attachment model this can only have one true value per asset.  I am wondering if there is a way to pull this record without looping through every record to see if main_image is set to true or false.

**Clarification:**

I can find the value by using the following code:

```
<% @asset.attachments.each_with_index do |attachment, i| %>
    <%= image_tag(attachment.attachment.s_640_480) if !attachment.main_image.nil? && attachment.main_image%>
<%end%>
```

but, I am wondering how to do this without a loop...
I don't know how to clarify any more...but something like:

```
 <%= image_tag(@attachment.where_main_image.s_640_480) %>
```

I know that won't work but basically that is the concept

Comment: I suppose I almost understand the problem, but could you post some simplified code examples, so we will be sure?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Currently, I cannot comprehend, what setup you have and what do you want.

Comment: @Arsen7 Gupta I have tried to clarify, sorry if it is still confusing.

Comment: Now it's much better ;-) A pity that a good answer has been already posted. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= image_tag(@asset.attachments.find_by_main_image(true).attachment.s_640_480) %>
```

It's not so nice to have this code in your view, so I'd recommend to put it in an instance method of your asset model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments

  def main_image 
    attachments.find_by_main_image(true).attachment.s_640_480
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
<%= image_tag(@asset.main_image) %>
```

You probably have to add some checks that objects are not nil. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can join it up like so:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attachments do
        def main_image
            where(:main_image => true).first
        end
    end
end
```

Use in your views like so:

```
<%= image_tag @asset.attachments.main_image.s640_480 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understant you need to find some entries in database if the value of it is true or false right ?

So you need to make a method inside your model or use a find with condition in the controller, you can find all what you want inside [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).