# Rails anyway to add an if statement to a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application I have a set of attachments that display, with a main image being one of them.  However, I would like to loop through all of them except the main attachment.  My view code right now is:

```
   <% if @asset.attachments.size > 0 %>
    <table>
        <tr>
    <% @asset.attachments.each_with_index do |attachment, i| %>
    <% if i%5 == 0 %>
        </tr><tr>
        <%end%>
    <td style="width: 150px;" valign="bottom" align="center">
    <%= image_tag(attachment.attachment.url(:thumb)) if attachment.is_image? %>
    <%= image_tag("/images/Excel.png") if attachment.is_excel? %>
    <%= image_tag("/images/Word.png") if attachment.is_word?%>
    <br />
    <%= link_to attachment.name.to_s,attachment.attachment.to_s %>
    </td>  
    <%end%>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <%end%>
```

but, I would like to add something like if !main_image to this line of code:

```
<% @asset.attachments.each_with_index do |attachment, i| %>
```

I don't know if that is possible though.

Comment: add another method to your model, which returns attachments that are not main image. Continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845650/rails-get-one-record-without-loop.

Comment: @Rubish Gupta please put this in an answer and I will accept it as the best answer, because I believe all the other ways would increase i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is in continuation to answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845650/rails-get-one-record-without-loop)

Add another method to your model, which return you the attachments which are not main image.

```
scope :not_main_image, where(:main_image => false)
```

On a side note, you might want to move all this logic into a helper method:

```
<%= image_tag(attachment.attachment.url(:thumb)) if attachment.is_image? %>
<%= image_tag("/images/Excel.png") if attachment.is_excel? %>
<%= image_tag("/images/Word.png") if attachment.is_word?%>
<br />
<%= link_to attachment.name.to_s,attachment.attachment.to_s>
```

Say you create a helper method like:

```
def link_to_attachment attachment
  html = ""
  html += image_tag(attachment.attachment.url(:thumb)) if attachment.is_image?
  html += image_tag("/images/Excel.png") if attachment.is_excel?
  html += image_tag("/images/Word.png") if attachment.is_word?
  html += "<br />"
  html += link_to(attachment.name.to_s, attachment.attachment.to_s)
  html.html_safe
end
```

Then in you view you can replace it with:

```
<td style="width: 150px;" valign="bottom" align="center">
  <%= link_to_attachment attachment %>
</td>
```

Comment: it should really be a scope rather than a function

Comment: @klochner, yes that would be better

Answer (score 2):

```
<% @asset.attachments.each_with_index do |attachment, i| %>
  <% next if attachment.main_image %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define the main attachment

```
<% @asset.attachments.each_index do |attachment, i| %>
  <% unless attachment.main? %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

OR

```
<% @asset.attachments.each_index do |attachment, i| %>
  <% if attachment.main? %>
    <% next %>
  <% else %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

OR put this in your controller

```
@attachments = @asset.attachments.where(:main => false)
```

after that, iterate over `@attachments` instead of `@asset.attachments`